# Change php img resizer class to prevent upscaling/pixelating images (by adding whitespace)

Tags: php

I'm using this php class (http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/articles/php-image-resizing.php) for creating the different sized images that my website requires.

I am using the *resizeToWidth()* method.

Everything is great except for if I'm requesting an output-width greater than the original, then the image is upscaled and pixelated to meet the dimensions.

*What's the best way of,
if the image is too small,
keeping the original image and padding out the background/cavas with white space to meet required width?*

```
 function resizeToWidth($width) {
  $ratio = $width / $this->getWidth();
  $height = $this->getheight() * $ratio;
  $this->resize($width,$height);}
```

calls:

```
 function resize($width,$height) {
  $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
  imagecopyresampled($new_image, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $this->getWidth(), $this->getHeight());
  $this->image = $new_image; }
```

I'm thinking i need:

1. An if statement in the resizeToWidthStatement
2. an extra parameter ie 'pad=true' in the resize() method
3. something in the resize() method that centres the image and adds the whitespace

any ideas?

Comment: You already gave the answers ... There must be an if clause to check for smaller image and a centering method, but no extra pad=true as that can be checked in the resize method itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track. Put a conditional check into the resizeToWidth to check if you're resizing up.

In the resize method, if you want to pad, then first create a new image of the new, larger dimensions, then figure out the center point `( ( new_image_width - old_image_width ) / 2 )` and to an `imagecopy` to that new location.